# How can I decrease the generation time of Drosophila melanogaster?

Tags: entomology, development, drosophila

I have a gene deletion strain of *Drosophila melanogaster* made with CRIPR/Cas9, and now I have to clean the background of this strain (TM6C balancer background) by making backcrosses with wild type. Normally, it takes 12 days for the entire life cycle at 25°C.

**How can I decrease the generation time of *Drosophila melanogaster*?**

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. This is not simply an answer site, but instead a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help. Consequently, **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site. Adding sources/citations and telling us where you've already looked  would help make it clear that you've satisfied this requirement. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details. ——— Also, which "life stage", or do you mean lifecycle? Finally, please don't use bold text in excess — it doesn't add anything.

Comment: I've edited your post to (I hope) be a bit clearer. Please make sure I've not altered your intended meaning and if you like any of the wording I used please [edit] your title accordingly. ——— Also it would be good if you could mention whether there are any known environmental sensitivities due to your deletion (and tell us what you deleted unless that is secret). If for example your strain was heat sensitive, that would rule out trying growth at increased temperature.

Answer (score 1):

The [Bloomington Drosophila Stock Center](https://bdsc.indiana.edu/information/fly-culture.html) has a lot of information on *Drosophila* stock propagation. Their **Working with Drosophila Stocks** guide includes the following excerpt:

> The frequency with which new subcultures need to be established depends on the health and fecundity of the genotype, the temperature at which it is raised, and the density of the cultures. Temperature has a large effect on the rate of Drosophila development. Generation time (from egg to adult) is approximately: 7 days at 29°C, 9 days at 25°C, 11 days at 22°C, 19 days at 18°C.

So, try keeping your flies at 29°C.

Comment: Thank you very much。 I try it.

Comment: @WiKC — If this answer [addressed your problem](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. Once you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.

Comment: @tyersome thanks for the edit, I misread the question

Comment: You're welcome!